# Is it possible figure out which URLs links to a question on P.SE?

Tags: discussion

It's too sooner to try Google. I want know if P.SE have some public information about the referrer of landed page.

My question had a huge traffic today.

[Question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1785/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-programming)

Comment: Can you expand on what you're looking for? Every URL has starts with http://programmers.stackexchange.com, and Google *is* indexing the site.

Comment: I wanna know where came this traffic. Google does not index real time every site in the internet.

Comment: Not every site, but it *does* index SE sites fairly quickly (within a few seconds to a few hours) because they have high pagerank.

Comment: I will repeat: It's too sooner to try Google. I tried yet.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? http://www.google.com.br/search?q=link:programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @bigown: http://www.google.com.br/search?hl=pt-BR&q=site%3Aprogrammers.stackexchange.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Comment: @TheLQ: this is a completely different thing. Your search is about P.SE, my search is about sites linking to P.SE.

Comment: @bigown: Sorry, didn't know google could do that. Apparently though nothing is linked, which is wrong. I have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Joel](http://www.joelonsoftware.com) added it at [Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com) — see [What should every programmer know about programming?](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1695156).